# Write a shell script that runs an program that requires input with cin

Tags: shell

In detail, I wrote a shell snippet, like this:

```
while read input
do
  ./a.out
done < "$1"
```

"$1" is test file with several rows. Each row is one test case.

a.out is compiled C++ file which my test cases run against.
The C++ source code is like this:

```
while (1) {
  cout << "Enter:\n"
  if ((cin >> v1) && (cin >> v2)) {
    cout << v1 << "\n";
    cout << v2 << "\n";
  }
}
```

We **are not** allowed to make a.out take parameters like this:
./a.out [parameters]

For example, the test file contains two test cases:

```
"a b"
"c d"
```

What I expect is, after running over my script,

```
a
b
c
d
```

should be output. Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. `cout <<` looks like C++, not shell! Edit your question to improve it and show what you have tried and what sort of input or output you want.

Comment: Hi Basile, I have updated the description of my confusion to make it clearer. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Are there actually quotes in the test file? What type are `v1` and `v2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say that your full code was this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int v1, v2;
    std::cin >> v1;
    std::cin >> v2;
    std::cout << "v1: " << v1 << " v2: " << v2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If the file that you are reading in your script has lines that look like this:

```
4 5
6 7
```

Then the loop in your shell script loop could be written like this:

```
while read input
do
    echo "$input" | ./a.out
done < "$1"
```

Running your shell script like `./script.sh file` would give the following output:

```
v1: 4 v2: 5
v1: 6 v2: 7
```

Comment: What if the program requires user input repeatedly in a loop? I was thinking about a way to terminate the program in my shell script. In that case, the behavior is similar to the code without any loop. How could we do that? Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on how many inputs you require, the structure of your file, etc. If you edit your question to provide more specifics, then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I may only have four lines of input in test file. The structure of it is like what you mentioned above. The loop of the source file is like the code snippet in my initial post. Thanks

Comment: So do you only want to run the C++ program once but pass all four lines to it?

Comment: No requirement. Either run C++ once but pass all four test cases or run C++ four times and each time test one test case. Anyway, if the test cases are "a b"\n"c d". Then they should be printed out on console in two lines

Comment: So would it be sufficient to simply do `./a.out < file` (no shell script required)? This passes the content of `file` to your program on standard input.

Answer (score 0):

[here documents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) might help. They can contain variables, and you could fill them.

Read also [advanced bash scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

If your `a.out` can process a single line, try also [pipes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) like

```
echo $A $B | a.out
```

or maybe use [printf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) instead of `echo` above

Answer (score 0):

If your C++ program needs some kind of text-based interactive interaction, expect might be a good choice (see http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).